# Debian 9 - Default Gnome desktop - does not display package updates available and other updates is grayed out in Software and Updates

Tags: debian, updates

I'm running Debian 9 with the standard Gnome 3 desktop.

It does not prompt to say there are new updates, I would like it to do this and display a notification on the desktop.

Also when I navigate to:

Software & Updates > Updates

The dropdown for 'When there are other updates' is greyed out.

Many thanks

Daniel

Comment: Please run this command and show us the output of it. `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

# stretch back ports

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main

Comment: I've sorted out update notifications, install tweak tools and add Software to Startup Applications (need to test for consistency). But would to clarify why dropdown for 'When there are other updates' is greyed out.